# How to make text appear under child in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I use Recycle View in my code and I have a parent a child. It successfully works and when I click on my parent a child appears. What my problem is, I don't know how to make a text appear below my child when clicking on it. Here is a pic to make this more clear.

In the picture I want when pressing child 0 a text to appear right below.
[image]

Comment: You have to add the extra "This child is even" textView in your layout, make the font smaller and set the text !

Comment: No, you didn't get me, I want this text to be displayed after clicking the child below. In contrary this is always displayed. Whats more I want to add a lot of text not a single line

Comment: You can put an Empty text below with no value, Then use ClickListener to set the text when user clicks on the "Child 1 or Child 2" etc, you can make use of android:visibility="gone" as well...to hide it UNTIL a click occurs

Comment: I have thought of something similar but how will I move the child's downwards so it look like its expanding?

Comment: "move the child's downwards so it look like its expanding?" -- am not sure about this but you can use Android animation for your text to slide down after Child Click